# I want to select all rows in a larger dataset, whose identification number, exists in another dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset, lets call it df1 (4226 observations X 186 variables)

I used a package called naniar to assess missingness, and created a dataset that shows, for each observation, what the percentage of missing data is. I then filtered the dataset, to show me only the observations (rows), in which there was less then 50% of missing data. Then, I created a dataset of just the row number of all rows that fit the missingness criteria, we can call this df2

Now, I want to create a subset of dataset df1 using the data in df2 (2044 observations X 1 variable).

Can anyone help me here?

I have tried something like:

```
df3 <- df2[df2$row %in% df1]
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We don't need your actual data. You can just include a small examples to make things more clear.

Comment: table = v1 , v2, v3, v4
          1     .     .      .
          2   1      1     .
          3   .      .      1
          4    1    .       1

Since I only want observations with missingness less than %50, I would only want rows 2 and 4. I

Comment: looks like you want to do filtering joins. Read the documentation for `semi_join()` from dplyr package.

Comment: Perfect that is exactly it.

Comment: Maybe swap the df's and match the column, not df2: `df3 <- df2[df1$row %in% df2$row,]`. And those are row indices, you forgot the comma.